# Access Files for Custodian Account from Admin Account OneDrive SDK CSharp, is there a way to automate this?

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am coding against the OneDrive C# SDK. I have set up a OneDrive for business where I have multiple global admins and a collection of users. I already have proofed out the ability for an admin to login and access a custodian (non-admin) accounts OneDrive files and folder.

The current workflow is as so:

1. Admin signs into https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/homepage
2. Navigate to "Users" on left navigation
3. Expand "Active Users"
4. Click a Custodian account
5. Expand OneDrive Settings
6. Click "Access Files" to grant permissions to manage this user's OneDrive

This is the only way currently that I am able to access a Custodian user's OneDrive files and folder from an Admin account.

My question is if there is a way to automate this process instead of having to have the Admin follow the workflow above?